# If $p$ is a prime number of the form $p=8k+3$ show that $2^s\equiv 1,s=(p-1)/2$ is not possible or find a counterexample

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number of the form $p=8k+3$ and $s=(p-1)/2$. Either prove that $2^s\equiv 1$  (mod $p$) is not possible or find a counterexample. I have checked primes under $10^6$ an couldn't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

A prime of the form $p=8k+3$ does not have $2$ as a quadratic residue (only the
 primes of the form $8k-1$ and $8k+1$ have). By Euler's criterion, it follows

$$2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\ \equiv\  -1\ (\ mod\  p\ )$$

Comment: Then perhaps $2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1 $ (mod $p$) could be used  as a test for primality for those primes because the smallest pseudoprime I came up with is $476971$. Interestingly this is not a Carmichael number.

Comment: Indeed. The test if $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ p\ )$ is based on Fermat's little theorem, and there are several refinements of this test.